# What is the integral of the t-distribution function?

Tags: p-value, t-distribution

The t-distribution probability density function is given by:

$f(x) =  \frac{\Gamma(\frac{\nu+1}{2})}{\sqrt{\nu\pi}\Gamma(\frac{\nu}{2})}(1+\frac{x^2}{\nu})^{-\frac{\nu+1}{2}}$

Is there an integral of this function such that you could calculate the p-value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral of the t-distribution *density* function (PDF) that you present is the [cummulative distribution function (CDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), which you are looking for, see e.g. [Wikipedia - Student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student's_t-distribution):

[image]

Be careful with the terminology here :-) In the title you say *"t-distribution function"* but it is actually *"probability density function of a t-distribution"* (you got it right in the question body) :) And you are looking for its integral, i.e. the *"cummulative distribution function of a t-distribution"* :-)

Comment: Thank you. What are the commas, and semi-colons separating? I'm not formally exposed to this subject and haven't seen that notation.

Comment: @JacksonCapper these are the parameters of the hypergeometric function. But I don't think you need to worry about this, since you don't have to program that function yourself: in almost all programming frameworks you can use a built-in CDF function. For example, in R, it is the `pt()` function: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/TDist.html